# Bijection for two sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Give a bijection between the set of odd numbers and the set of even numbers and provide proof that it is a bijection.

Would this be a feasible bijection:

If $a$ is odd, then $a-1$ is even.

How would I provide a proof, that this is bijective? I understand that this is a bijection in that it is surjective and injective as each element only maps to one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, you just need to make it more formal; also maybe write down its inverse too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're saying that your function $f : \{ \text{odds} \} \to \{ \text{evens} \}$ is given by $f(a)=a-1$.

This function certainly works. To show $f$ is bijective you need to show that:

- $f$ is well-defined, i.e. given any odd number $a$, $f(a)$ really *is* even;
- $f$ is injective, i.e. if $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a=b$;
- $f$ is surjective, i.e. given any even number $n$ there is an odd number $a$ such that $f(a)=n$.

When you've proved that $f$ is well-defined, injective and surjective then, by definition of what it means to be bijective, you've proved that $f$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the mapping $\phi:a\mapsto a-1$ is indeed a bijection from the set of odd integers to the set of even integers (I assume, negative integers are included, but it doesn't really make any difference).

I think, the easiest argument now is that the mapping $\psi:b\mapsto b+1$ is an *inverse* of $\phi$, in that
$$\phi(\psi(b))=b\quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad \psi(\phi(a))=a$$
for all odd $a$ and even $b$.

Answer (score 0):

How do provide a proof in general in mathematics? You have to show that the definition required in the problem holds.

In this case, you are asked to come up with a bijection. So you came up with a function, $f(n)=n-1$ defined for the odd numbers (I'm assuming integers, or natural numbers). This is of course a function, otherwise you'd have to verify that this is indeed a function.

Next to verify that the definition of a bijection holds. So we need to verify that the definition of "injective" is true for this $f$, as the definition of surjective.

Recall that a function is injective if and only if for different inputs it gives different outputs. Equivalently, if the output is equal, the input was equal. Assume that $n$ and $k$ are two odd integers. We have that $$f(n)=f(k)\iff f(n)+1=f(k)+1\iff n=k.$$

Therefore $f$ is injective. To show that $f$ is surjective we have to show that given an even number, $m$ there exists an odd number $n$ such that $f(n)=m$. I will leave this to you to verify.